# Solving equations involving dozens of ceil and floor functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am tackling a problem which uses lots of equations in the form of:

[image]

where q_i(x) is the only unknown, c_i, C_j, P_j are always positive. We have two cases, the first when c_i, C_j, P_j are integers and the case when they are real. C_j < P_j for all j

1. How is this type of problems efficently solved in MATLAB especially when the number of iterations N is between 20 - 100?

What I was doing is q_i(x) - c_i(x) must be equal to the summation of integers. So i was doing an exhaustive search for q_i(x) which satisfies both ends of the equation. Clearly this is computationally exhaustive.

1. What if c_i(x) is a floating point number, this will even make the problem even more difficult to find a real q_i(x)?

***MORE INFO:*** These equations are from the paper "Integrating Preemption Threshold to Fixed Priority DVS Scheduling Algorithms" by Yang and Lin.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an assumption that c_i is an integer? Please describe the problem clearly with all assumptions about all variables.

Comment: question edited to give all assumptions

Comment: How about (q*C/P), what makes you think this is an integer? Or do you mean the division is an integer (floor) division?

Comment: Q/P is an integer due to the floor function. The first assumption is that C is an integer so Q/P * C is an integer! I did not tackle the second case where C and P are reals yet!

Comment: Do you have an estimation that the solution should lie in some range?

Answer (score 0):

The sum is a step function. You can discretize the problem by calculating where the floor function jumps for the next value; this is periodic for every j. Then you overlay the N ''rhythms'' (each has its own speed specified by the Pj) and get all the locations where the sum jumps. Each segment can have exactly 0 or 1 intersection with qi(x). You should visualize the problem for intuitive understanding like this:

```
f = @(q) 2 + (floor(q/3)*0.5 + floor(q/4)*3 + floor(q/2)*.3);
xx = -10:0.01:10;
plot(xx,f(xx),xx,xx)
```

[image: Step function visualization]

For each step, it can be checked analytically if an intersection exists or not.

```
jumps = unique([0:3:10,0:4:10,0:2:10]); % Vector with position of jumps
lBounds = jumps(1:end-1); % Vector with lower bounds of stairs
uBounds = jumps(2:end); % Vector with upper bounds of stairs
middle = (lBounds+uBounds)/2; % center of each stair
fStep = f(middle); % height of the stairs
intersection = fStep; % Solution of linear function q=fStep
% Check if intersection is within the bounds of the specific step
solutions = intersection(intersection>=lBounds & intersection<uBounds)

2.3000    6.9000
```

Comment: Basically this is what I have been doing via my exhaustive search. Samr thing but different representation. This does not solve the issue if $c_i$ is real as how small can you go in discretisation so that u don't miss the solution. (plus this is limited by the computer FP representation precision)

Comment: Simply, based on your example, you chose 0.01 intervals. What if the xx value which satisfies both hands of the equation is at a precision of 0.001, clearly u will miss that solution.

Comment: You can calculate the step positions analytically. q/3 produces steps at 0,3,6,9,…; q/4 produces steps at 0,4,8,12,…; q/2 at 0,2,4,6,…. You overlay all of them on a predefined interval, like -100…100 and check each segment if it has an intersection.

Comment: Sure. I get that. But take this numerical example. f = @(q) 2.75 + (1.3333*floor(q/2.3) + 2.3*floor(q/4.123)); x = 0:0.01:20;
>> plot(x, f(x), x, x) A solution exists for 4.0833 (only solution) but at steps of 0.01 it is missed. The extreme case is when a solution exists at a resolution lower than what the IEEE floating point standard is able to represent. But still, assuming that solutions exist within the represntable format, how to choose the search interval to balance speed and getting a result

Comment: I added working code in my answer. For your example, use jumps = unique([0:2.3:10,0:4.123:10]). The right step size to use in this problem is the not-equidistant jump spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to numerically find zeros of almost any well-behavior functions.

1. Convert your equation problem into a zero-finding problem, by moving all things to one side of the equal sign. Then find `x: f(x)=0`.
2. Apply bisection method equation solver.

That's it! Or may be....

- If you have specific range(s) where the roots should fall in, then just perform bisection method for each range. If not, you still have to give a maximum estimation (you don't want to try some number larger than that), and make this as the range.
- The problem of this method is for each given range it can only find one root, because it's always picking the left (or right) half of the range. That's OK if P_j is integer, as you can always find a minimum step of the function. Say P_j = 1, then only a change in q_i *larger than 1* leads to another segment (and thus a possible different root). Otherwise, within each range shorter than 1 there will be at most one solution.
- If P_j is an arbitrary number (such as 1e-10), unless you have a lower limit on P_j, most likely you are out of lucky, since you can't tell how fast the function will jump, which essentially means `f(x)` is not a well-behavior function, making it hard to solve.